# Acumatica Link Between CROpportunity and SOOrders - Generic Inquiry

Tags: acumatica

R2 was recently released and there is a need to get the relationships between CROpportunity and SOOrder to add to the Sales Order entry screen (the Generic Inquiry). What is the relationship between both of these DACs? Are there other DACs which need to be included instead of a direct link?

**1st Try**

I have tried using CROpportunity to FSServiceOrder and then FSServiceOrder to SOOrder using the below:

- CROpportunity/FSService Order on SOID/SOID
- FSServiceOrder/SOOrder on refNbr/sourceRefNbr

**2nd Try**

I also tried doing a direct relationship between CROpportunity to SOOrder using:

- CROpportunity/SOOrder on externalRef/sourceRefNbr

Using this, also:

- CROpportunity/SOOrder on externalRef/externalRef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the relationship between Opportunities and Sales Orders try the pattern below. Recent versions of Acumatica now allow a 1 to many relationship between opportunities and sales orders.

This is the SQL link to help clarify the screen shots for the GI.

```
select o.CompanyID, o.OrderDate, o.OrderNbr, r.RefNoteID, r.Role, p.OpportunityID 
from SOOrder o
inner join CRRelation r on o.NoteID = r.RefNoteID and r.CompanyID = o.CompanyID
inner join CROpportunity p on p.NoteID = r.TargetNoteID and r.Role = 'SR' and p.CompanyID = r.CompanyID
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]